# Re-ordering arrays

Tags: c#, xna

How do I re-arrange Array X, based on the size of corresponding values in Array Y.

Here's what I mean in pseudo code:

```
Array X = Red, Yellow, Green, Blue

Array Y = 68.4, 42.3, 53.6, 69.3 (random positive doubles)
```

I want an output of:

```
Array Z = Blue, Red, Green, Yellow
```

i.e. The it ranks the elements of Array Y by size (and so it goes to 69.4, 68.3, 53.6, 42.3), and then applies that same re-ordering to the elements of Array X, re ordering it to Blue, Red, Green, Yellow

My attempt so far is creating a list that adds the elements, re-orders them using the list.sort method, but its a complete mess to be honest because I can't get my head round the logic required.

EDIT - using doubles instead of ints

Comment: If these values are related, perhaps you should store them together. If they are not related, you need to set up a map between them. Then you can sort one collection, iterate through that and look up elements in the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an overload of `Array.Sort` specifically for this.

Just use:

```
Array.Sort(Y, X);
```

Having said that, while you can do this, I would strongly suggest that you create a single array of some composite item, having both a `Color` and a `int` value, and then sort it based on the int, rather than having two different arrays in which the index of each array corresponds to one component of "something".  It will make dealing with it easier.

Comment: +1 That't work too :) I didn't know about this overload. Thanks!

Comment: He'll also need to reverse Y after.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault That or provide a comparer that sorts in descending order, yes.

Comment: This looks like it might be the answer. The only thing is I've slightly over simplified my example, I actually want to arrange by doubles (see edit above). Is there a way to convert the array of doubles to a rank, and then do this?

Comment: @user2056166 This will work just fine with doubles.  It will work with anything that can be sorted by `Array.Sort` (which, if you include custom comparers, is pretty much anything).

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> colors = new List<string>() { "Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue" };
List<double> order = new List<double>() { 68.4, 42.3, 53.6, 69.3 };

var newList = order.Select((item, inx) => new { item, inx })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.item)
                .Select(x => colors[x.inx])
                .ToList();
```

Comment: change that last ToList() call for a ToArray() and you got my vote ... OP did ask for an array at the end of it all.

Answer (score 0):

This may helps:

```
List<Tuple<string, int>> values = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
values.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Red", 68));
values.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Yellow", 42));
values.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Green", 53));

var sortedValues = values.OrderByDescending(i => i.Item2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list of key-value pairs you would get better results, then you could simply sort by the values and output an array or list of the keys.

Something like the Compare2 method in this article is what you are looking for:  http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-keyvaluepair